# Filtering array of objects by searching nested object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects that I want to filter by comparing a nested property to a search term.

For example:

```
 var array = [
      {category: 'Business'
       users: [
                {name: 'Sally'
                 tags: [{tag: 'accounting'}, {tag: 'marketing'},...]
                },
                {name: 'Bob'
                 tags: [{tag: 'sales'}, {tag: 'accounting'},...]
                }...
              ]
       },
       {category: 'Heritage'
        users: [
                 {name: 'Linda'
                  tags: [{tag: 'Italy'}, {tag: 'Macedonia'},...]
                 },
                 {name: 'George'
                  tags: [{tag: 'South Africa'}, {tag: 'Chile'},...]
                 },...
               ]
       },...
    [
```

Essentially I want to filter the base array of objects by a search terms that include characters from the tag property string in the nested objects 2 arrays down.

So a search for 'market' would result in

```
[
  {category: 'Business'
   users: [
            {name: 'Sally'
             tags: [{tag: 'accounting'}, {tag: 'marketing'},...]
            },
            {name: 'Bob'
             tags: [{tag: 'sales'}, {tag: 'accounting'},...]
            }...
          ]
   }
]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with looking into the nested arrays by using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

If the tag is found in a nested array, then iteration stops and the result is given back to the filter callback.

```js
var array = [{ category: 'Business', users: [{ name: 'Sally', tags: [{ tag: 'accounting' }, { tag: 'marketing' }] }, { name: 'Bob', tags: [{ tag: 'sales' }, { tag: 'accounting' }] }] }, { category: 'Heritage', users: [{ name: 'Linda', tags: [{ tag: 'Italy' }, { tag: 'Macedonia' }] }, { name: 'George', tags: [{ tag: 'South Africa' }, { tag: 'Chile' }] }] }],
    tag = 'marketing',
    result = array.filter(a => a.users.some(u => u.tags.some(t => t.tag.includes(tag))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If I wanted to compare with two values?

Comment: @nicogaldo swap the last `tag` around with `t.tag` to enable multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `Array.prototype.some()` function:

```js
var arr = [{ category: 'Business', users: [{ name: 'Sally', tags: [{ tag: 'accounting' }, { tag: 'marketing' }] }, { name: 'Bob', tags: [{ tag: 'sales' }, { tag: 'accounting' }] }] }, { category: 'Heritage', users: [{ name: 'Linda', tags: [{ tag: 'Italy' }, { tag: 'Macedonia' }] }, { name: 'George', tags: [{ tag: 'South Africa' }, { tag: 'Chile' }] }] }], 
    search_key = 'market',
    result = [];
    
arr.forEach(function(o){
    if (o.users.some(function(v){
        return v.tags.some(function(i){ return i.tag.indexOf(search_key) !== -1; });
    })) {
        result.push(o);
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a great answer Roman, thank you. I just accepted Nina's because her's was added first and a little more concise. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function search(term){
return
    Array.filter(array,function(item){
       return JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf(term)!=-1;
    });
}
```

So :

```
console.log(search('market'));
```

I hope to be helpful for you:)

Comment: This also searches the keys, so if you search for "tag" you'll find every object matches.

Answer (score 1):

The `concatAll` and `concatMap` definitions are taken from http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push.apply(results, subArray);
    });

    return results;
};

Array.prototype.concatMap = function(projectionFunctionThatReturnsArray) {
    return this.
        map(function(item) {
            return projectionFunctionThatReturnsArray(item);
        }).
        // apply the concatAll function to flatten the two-dimensional array
        concatAll();
};

function filterByTags(keyword) {
  return array.filter(function (item) {
    var allTags = item.users.concatMap(function (user) {
      return user.tags.map(function (tag) {
        return tag.tag;
      });
    });

    return allTags.some(function (tag) {
      return tag.indexOf(keyword) > -1;
    });
  });
}

console.log(filterByTags('market'));
```

Of course you could inline the `allTags` variable for more conciseness.

The `filter` applied to the initial array will return all items that have users whose tags contain the keyword supplied. The strategy is to build a flattened version of the users' tags and apply `some` on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.filter` like this:

```
function getFiltered(val) {
     return array.filter(category == val);
}
```

This function will return a new array instance, only with the `category` keys you passed as the `val` params.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am taking a shortcut-like approach to this, primarily to provide a different perspective to the problem.

Instead of deep-searching the properties and arrays under the main `array`, you can create a json string of the `users` property and search within that. So I have created a new property `usersString` that temporarily stores the JSON string of the value against `users` property.

```
item.usersString = JSON.stringify(item.users);
```

Now, this would not be a perfect implementation, but it would almost always work. Also, if you stored this property within the browser (without storing it back to the DB), and used it to quick-search for every time user searches, I think it would be more performant that deep-searching entire array.

```js
var array = [{
    category: 'Business',
    users: [{
        name: 'Sally',
        tags: [{
          tag: 'accounting'
        }, {
          tag: 'marketing'
        }]
      },
      {
        name: 'Bob',
        tags: [{
          tag: 'sales'
        }, {
          tag: 'accounting'
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    category: 'Heritage',
    users: [{
        name: 'Linda',
        tags: [{
          tag: 'Italy'
        }, {
          tag: 'Macedonia'
        }]
      },
      {
        name: 'George',
        tags: [{
          tag: 'South Africa'
        }, {
          tag: 'Chile'
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];

var key = "market";

// Convert the users property into a string - so that it works as a quick search target.
array.forEach(function(item) {
  item.usersString = JSON.stringify(item.users);
});


var filteredItems = array.filter(function(item) {
  return item.usersString.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
});

// Delete the usersString property - if required.
filteredItems.forEach(function(item) {
  item.usersString = undefined;
  // Or,
  // delete item.usersString;
})

console.log(filteredItems);
```