# How to filter array of objects by an array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, javascript-objects

I have a recipes array filled with objects. An object looks like this

```
var recipes = [
  {
    name: 'All-Purpose Rub for Meat',
    ingredients: [
      {
        name: 'white sugar',
        quantity: {
          number: 4,
          unit: 'tablespoon'
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'salt',
        quantity: {
          number: 4,
          unit: 'tablespoon'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'paprika',
        quantity: {
          number: 1,
          unit: 'tablespoon'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'mustard powder',
        quantity: {
          number: 2,
          unit: 'tablespoon'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'ground black pepper',
        quantity: {
          number: .5,
          unit: 'teaspoon'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'dried oregano',
        quantity: {
          number: 1,
          unit: 'pinch'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'dried thyme',
        quantity: {
          number: 1,
          unit: 'pinch'
        }
      },
    ],
    servingSize: {
      quantity: 12,
      unit: 'servings'
    },
    // usedFor: [ribs, chicken, pork, fish, beef]
  },


  {
    name: 'Rosemary Garlic Rub',
    ingredients: [{
      name: 'ground black pepper',
      quantity: {number: 1, unit: 'tablespoon'}},
      {
      name: 'kosher salt',
      quantity: {number: 1, unit: 'tablespoon'}},
      {
      name: 'chopped fresh rosemary',
      quantity: {number: 3, unit: 'tablespoon'}},
      {
      name: 'dried rosemary',
      quantity: {number: 1, unit: 'tablespoon'}},
      {
      name: 'diced garlic',
      quantity: {number: 8, unit: 'cloves'}},
      {
      name: 'olive oil',
      quantity: {number: .333, unit: 'cup'}}            
        ],
    servingSize: {quantity: 4, unit: 'servings'}, 
    // usedFor: [chicken, pork] 
  },
]
```

What I want to do is filter the recipes array based on an inputted spice, so it would be something like this

filterRecipes({name: 'ground black pepper'});

I've tried

```
function filterRecipes(spice) {
 let filteredarray = recipes.filter((recipe) => {
    recipe.ingredients.includes(spice.name);
 });
 return filteredarray;
}

console.log(filterRecipes({name: 'kosher salt'}))
```

The filterRecipes function would then return an array of all recipes where it had the ingredient ' ground black pepper.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**It looked like I would need something similar to his, but I cant use some because I need all** I dont know why its flagging the below as the correct answer, but that doesnt give me back all the items with the ingredients

[Filtering array of objects by searching nested object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575043/filtering-array-of-objects-by-searching-nested-object-properties)

It should return an array of recipes with only objects that have the ingredient that was put as a parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering array of objects by searching nested object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575043/filtering-array-of-objects-by-searching-nested-object-properties)

Comment: Your recipes.filter function does not return anything, I think once you fix that it should work.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I included that in my question that I couldnt use that

Answer (score 0):

`includes()` is not the right choice here, try `some()` instead for your `filterRecipes` function:

```
function filterRecipes(recipes, ingredient) {
  return recipes.filter(({ ingredients }) => {
    return ingredients.some(({ name }) => name === ingredient);
  });
}
```

...and then call it with ingredient name, not the object:

```
filterRecipes(recipes, 'kosher salt');
```

You can learn more about `.some()` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)