# How can I filter nested objects and arrays with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

My use case is something like this.

1. I have an array that has an object.
2. That each object has an array called `menu`
3. Again that menu array has objected.
4. That each object has an array `dish_has_categories`
5. In `dish_has_categories` array, if there is an object with CategoryId is equal to `8` I want to filter out that root object.

**My original data object**

```js
const data = [{
        menuName: "Hot dogs",
        menu: [
            {
            dishId: '1',
            dish_has_categories: [{
                CategoryId: '8'
            }]
        },
         {
            dishId: '2',
            dish_has_categories: [{
                CategoryId: '9'
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        menuName: "Burgers",
        menu: [{
            dishId: '3',
            dish_has_categories: [{
                CategoryId: '6'
            }]
        }, {
            dishId: '4',
            dish_has_categories: [{
                CategoryId: '4'
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        name: "Drinks",
        menu: []
    }
]
```

**My expect result is**

```js
[{
        menuName: "Hot dogs",
        menu: [
            {
            dishId: '1',
            dish_has_categories: [{
                CategoryId: '8'
            }]
        },
         {
            dishId: '2',
            dish_has_categories: [{
                CategoryId: '9'
            }]
        }]
    }]
```

what I've done up to now is

```
const data2 = data.filter(element => {
    return element.menu.length > 0
})
```

I have no idea how to deep filter inside nested objects and arrays. Hope my question is clear to you all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering array of objects by searching nested object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575043/filtering-array-of-objects-by-searching-nested-object-properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Here nested some is used to check whether any of `dish_has_categories` has `CategoryId` equal to `'8'`, if it is `true` then we include that menu in final output else we don't

```js
const data =[{ menuName: "Hot dogs", menu: [ { dishId: '1', dish_has_categories: [{ CategoryId: '8' }] }, { dishId: '2', dish_has_categories: [{ CategoryId: '9' }] }] }, { menuName: "Burgers", menu: [{ dishId: '3', dish_has_categories: [{ CategoryId: '6' }] }, { dishId: '4', dish_has_categories: [{ CategoryId: '4' }] }] }, { name: "Drinks", menu: [] } ]

let op = data.filter(val => {
  let menu = val.menu.some(({dish_has_categories}) => dish_has_categories.some(({CategoryId}) => CategoryId === '8'))
  return menu
})

console.log('filtered values -->\n',op)

let names = op.map(({menuName})=> menuName)

console.log('Names --> \n', names)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works! If I want to push this menu name ("Hot dogs") to new separate array. Where do I can do that?

Comment: @PathumSamararathna you want to get names of filtered values or all the values ? you can simply use map and  return name only from map

Comment: @PathumSamararathna i have added example of getting names in new array too you can check :) always happy to help :)

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with nested [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value

```js
const data = [{ menuName: "Hot dogs", menu: [ { dishId: '1', dish_has_categories: [{ CategoryId: '8' }] }, { dishId: '2', dish_has_categories: [{ CategoryId: '9' }] }] }, { menuName: "Burgers", menu: [{ dishId: '3', dish_has_categories: [{ CategoryId: '6' }] }, { dishId: '4', dish_has_categories: [{ CategoryId: '4' }] }] }, { name: "Drinks", menu: [] } ]

const res = data.filter(x => 
                x.menu.some(y => 
                    y.dish_has_categories.some(z => z.CategoryId === '8')
                )
            );
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain, why you are using `z.CategoryId === '8'`? 8 is hardcoded here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works! If I want to push this menu name ("Hot dogs") to new separate array. Where do I can do that?

Comment: @PathumSamararathna You can use `map()` for that I have updated.

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen Becasue OP asked )"In dish_has_categories array, if there is an object with **CategoryId is equal to 8** I want to filter out that root object."_

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `filter()` and `some()` . `some()` method checks if any of the elements in an array pass the function.

```
let data2 = data.filter(element => {
    let menu = element.menu.some(({dish_has_categories}) => dish_has_categories.some(({CategoryId}) => CategoryId === '8'));
    return menu;
           });
    console.log(data2);
```