# Javascript or lodash : filter an array of objects with value of a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, lodash

I have an array of Users as below (I have shortened it):

```
 [
  {
    "displayName": "Alaotra",
    "districts": [
      {
        "regions_id_region": "11",            
        "id_district": "102"
      },
      {           
        "regions_id_region": "11",            
        "id_district": "101",          
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "displayName": "Alexandre",
    "districts": [
      {
        "regions_id_region": "42",
        "id_district": "411",           
      },
      {           
        "id_district": "409",           
        "regions_id_region": "42"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Each User has an array of Districts.
I want to get a filtered array of Users that has districts with "regions_id_region" = "11" for example. Lodash or Vanilla will be ok.
I spend the whole day trying to achieve it without any success.
Any help is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Add your attempt to the question

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javaScript filter nested objects and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371728/javascript-filter-nested-objects-and-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can use filter:

```js
const users = [{
    "displayName": "Alaotra",
    "districts": [{
        "regions_id_region": "11",
        "id_district": "102"
      },
      {
        "regions_id_region": "11",
        "id_district": "101",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "displayName": "Alexandre",
    "districts": [{
        "regions_id_region": "42",
        "id_district": "411",
      },
      {
        "id_district": "409",
        "regions_id_region": "42"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const filtered = users.filter(u => u.districts.some(d => d.regions_id_region === '11'))
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, i waq very useful. What would be the best approach if "regions_id_region" is in an array? ["11","42" ]?