# Filtering a nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a heavily nested object which looks like this:

```js
data = [{
    id: 1, 
    tables: {
        headers: [
            {headerName: 'First Name', 
             values: [
                 {id: 1, text_value: 'John', unique_id: '3UPYR2'}
                 {id: 2, text_value: 'Nick', unique_id: 'WKKHCM'}
             ]}, 

             {headerName: 'Last Name', 
             values: [
                 {id: 1, text_value: 'Doe', unique_id: '3UPYR2'}
                 {id: 2, text_value: 'Smith', unique_id: 'WKKHCM'}
             ]}
        ]
    } 
}]
```

What I want to do is filter out this object but query it on the `unique_id` attribute for each header so that I can create an object like so:

```js
data = [{
    id: 1, 
    tables: {
        headers: [
            {headerName: 'First Name', 
             values: [
                 {id: 1, text_value: 'John', unique_id: '3UPYR2'}
             ]}, 

             {headerName: 'Last Name', 
             values: [
                 {id: 1, text_value: 'Doe', unique_id: '3UPYR2'}
             ]}
        ]
    } 
}]
```

I tried implementing the solution on this post ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371728/how-can-i-filter-nested-objects-and-arrays-with-javascript#:~:text=Here%20nested%20some%20is%20used%20to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371728/how-can-i-filter-nested-objects-and-arrays-with-javascript#:%7E:text=Here%20nested%20some%20is%20used%20to)) but this just returns the original object.

I updated this implementation like so:

```js
let filetered = data.filter(rec => {
    let final = rec.table.some(({headers}) => headers.some(({values}) => values.some(({unique_id}) => unique_id === myUniqueId)))
    return final
})
```

Not entirely sure how this is working or what is going wrong here.

Comment: What is `resCopy` and `rec`? Your variable is named `data`.

Comment: also is the id in the main object and the ids in headers related

Comment: Sorry about the typos, `resCopy` should have been `data` and `rec` is effectively just the entire data object. The id in the main object is not related to the id in `headers`

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem at all related to what you want to do.

Comment: Nothing in what you're doing needs `.some()`. That's for filtering an outer array if you can find a match in any of the inner array. But you just want to filter the `values` arrays directly, it's not so complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all the `header` and filter its `values` property.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1, 
    tables: {
        headers: [
            {headerName: 'First Name', 
             values: [
                 {id: 1, text_value: 'John', unique_id: '3UPYR2'},
                 {id: 2, text_value: 'Nick', unique_id: 'WKKHCM'}
             ]}, 

             {headerName: 'Last Name', 
             values: [
                 {id: 1, text_value: 'Doe', unique_id: '3UPYR2'},
                 {id: 2, text_value: 'Smith', unique_id: 'WKKHCM'}
             ]}
        ]
    } 
}]

const unique_id = "3UPYR2";
data.forEach(d => 
  d.tables.headers.forEach(h => 
    h.values = h.values.filter(v => v.unique_id == unique_id)))

console.log(data);
```