# deep filtering on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data like this one below

```
let data = [
{
    name: 'basic',
    to: 'aaa',
    subMenus: [
      {
        name: 'general conc',
        to: 'geneal',
      },
      {
        name: 'example view',
        to: 'example',
      },
      {
        name: 'fancy',
        to: 'bbb',
        innerSubMenus: [
          {
            name: 'adding',
            to: 'add',
          },
          {
            name: 'getting',
            to: 'get',
          },
          
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

]
```

I need to filter data based on name (in main, subMenus, and innerSubMenus)
Here is the piece of code

```
function deepFilter(inputText){
data.filter(items => items.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputText.toLowerCase()))
}
```

As you can see, the function filters the first prop (name --> basic in this case when inputText = 'basic', doesn't work when inputText = 'general conc') but I want to be able to filter names in subMenus and innerSubMenus as well. Please, guide me on how to do it. Thanks

expected outputs:

```
deepFilter('basic') -> true // only this part is covered by my implementation
deepFilter('general conc') -> true
deepFilter('adding') -> true
deepFilter('ffff') -> false //since there is not name with value of 'ffff' in data
```

Comment: Have you tried ```data.filter(items => items.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputText.toLowerCase()) && <other conditions>)```?

Comment: Make your life a little easier, and split up the responsibilities: `data.filter(items => preserveItem(item))` and then write a separate `function preserveItem(item)` that can return true or false depending on all the various conditions you need met. Now you've reduced the problem of "writing filtering code" to only writing out individual conditions that need to be met, and returning the "or" of their values. Fat arrow functions are super useful, but not if you need moderately complex code for which preserving declare-time-`this` is irrelevant, like here.

Comment: of course, it has to match the inputText

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering array of objects by searching nested object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575043/filtering-array-of-objects-by-searching-nested-object-properties)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, hmm not really! that filters only leaves

Comment: Which of the 6 answers is "that"? Also, [edit] your question to include the result you want, like multiple people have asked you to...

Comment: This is not filtering. The return value of `filter` is an array, not a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work well.

```js
function deepFilter(inputText, datas) {
    return datas.filter(data => {
        function checkInsideObj(object, inputText) {
            for (let value of Object.values(object)) {
                if (object.name && object.name.toLowerCase() === inputText.toLowerCase()) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                    return value.some(item => {
                        return checkInsideObj(item, inputText)
                    }
                    )
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return checkInsideObj(data, inputText)

    }
    )

}
deepFilter("input", data)
```

Comment: @Hakim it would have been been better if you had provided array with multiple items and then mentioned the result you expect.