# return charachetrs with the same key door

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects(characters) where each object has an array of objects(keys), a door can be opened by multiple keys as you can see in this example

```
const characters = [
  { id: "1", type: "water", keys: [{ name: "key_786", door: "XOPR" }] },
  { id: "2", type: "fire", keys: [{ name: "key_23", door: "JTHF" }] },
  { id: "3", type: "wind", keys: [{ name: "key_987", door: "XOPR" }] },
];
```

What I want is to find all the characters that have a key that can open one specific door, for example I want to return all characters with `keys.door === 'XOPR'` how can I do it ?

I tried .filter .map but no luck, some help please ? I am new to react and javascript

Comment: Show your attempts with `filter()` and we can help you fix it. (hint: `keys` is an array, so you need to access an index before you can access the object `keys[0].door === 'XOPR'`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering array of objects by searching nested object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575043/filtering-array-of-objects-by-searching-nested-object-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

```js
const result = characters.filter(ch => ch.keys.some(key => key.door === 'DOOR_NAME'));
```

First you `filter` through `characters` then for every one you loop through its `keys` property which is an array and for every item of this latter you chack if `key.door === 'DOOR_NAME'` so you return the `character` for this itteration(of the filter loop)